# How to get sum of array from two different input in two different components? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am building a budget calculator. I am taking the amount from one input and adding it to another input so I can come up with the balance. I have tried reduce and concat and they are coming up to sum but the value is wrong. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction. I think the problem is that the values are rendering twice and that's throwing off the math. I don't know.

Here is my code:

```
// this is the component to get the balance
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      balance: []
    }

  }
  getBalance = (total) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      balance: [prevState.balance, total].reduce((acc, currentVal) => {
        return Number(currentVal) + Number(acc)
      }, 0)
    }));

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <div className="count">
          <h2 className="balancetitle">Your Balance</h2>
          <h1 style={{ color: this.state.balance >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${this.state.balance}</h1>
        </div>
        <Transactions getBalance={(total) => this.getBalance(Number(total))} />
        <Income getBalance={(total) => this.getBalance(Number(total))} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


// this is the code to get the transaction. I have another component that is identical to get the sum of the income. 

const Transactions = (props) => {
    const [expenses, setExpense] = useState([])
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState([])
    const [id, setId] = useState([])
    const [listOfTrans, setListofTrans] = useState([])
    const [total, setTotal] = useState([0])


    //fires on click or enter
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        addExpense({
            amount,
            expenses,
            id
        });
        setAmount('')
        setExpense('')
    }

    //get value of inputs
    const getValue = (hookSetter) => (e) => {
        let { value } = e.target;
        return hookSetter(value)
    }
    // turn amount and expense into objects and put them setListofTranas
    const addExpense = (expenseObject) => {
        setListofTrans([...listOfTrans, expenseObject])

    }
    const show = () => {
        if (listOfTrans.legnth > 1) {
            return listOfTrans
        } else return null
    }
    // get total amount of listoftrans
    const getAmount = () => {

        if (listOfTrans.length > 0) {
            let listAmount = listOfTrans.map(list => {
                if (list.amount) {
                    return -Math.abs(list.amount);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            })

            return listAmount.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
                return Number(acc) + Number(currentValue)

            }, 0)
        } else return 0

    }


    //update amount total on click
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(getAmount())
        props.getBalance(getAmount())

    }, [listOfTrans])

    // delete item from array
    const deleteExpense = (i) => {
        let objExpense = i
        setListofTrans(listOfTrans.filter((list) => {
            return list.id !== objExpense
        }))
    }
```

Comment: Try spreading the `prevState.balance` array, using the `...` operator - like this: `[...prevState.balance, total]`

Comment: @GalAbra, Hi, I've tried that. It keeps saying that it's not iterable.

Comment: Oh, that's because inside `getBalance` you set `state.balance` to be a number :)

Comment: Where is the code for Income component?

Comment: @Asutosh, It's the exact same for the transaction component, just different words.

Comment: The problem is Transactions component returns nothing, is it for the question purpose?

Comment: How doesn't the Transactions component return nothing? I'm getting values from them.

Comment: I have created a code sandbox for your problem, check it. and it's rendering there well. https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sid-44xwt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @GalAbra How can make it iterable?

Comment: Inside `getBalance` - return `[value]` rather than `value`

Answer (score 0):

I am adding it here as the suggestion is not possible to add long description in comments section.

What you are doing buggy in the the solution above is making use of useEffect to do the calcualtions. The approach can be real buggy and difficult to debug.

```
//update amount total on click
    useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(getAmount())
        props.getBalance(getAmount())

    }, [listOfTrans])
```

In the code above `listOfTans` is an array , may be changing due to various operation, which cause the useEffect callback to run repeatedly. The callback is reponsible for updating the sum.

So instead of doing that, you should just call

```
props.getBalance(getAmount())
```

in onClick Handler.

This is just the suggestion for what I can understand from the question above.